# Copied code for dialog in material-ui from docs, but isn't working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, material-ui

I copied code for material-ui dialog feature for react, but couldn't figure out why this isn't working at all. Clicking the contact button doesn't even cause it to call the handleClickOpen method.

The contact button is the one that's supposed to open the dialog box, all the dialog code is copied from the docs of material-ui so I'm not sure how this couldn't be working.

```
export default function Banner() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  function handleClickOpen() {
    setOpen(true);
  }

  function handleClose() {
    setOpen(false);
  }
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="lg">

      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={7}>
          <Grid item lg={6} xs={12}>
            <div className={classes.title}>
              <Title content="Freightage Solutions" />
              <br />
              <SubTitle content="A lean, modern, and efficient shipping brokerage." />
              <div className={classes.buttons}>
                <Button ClassName={classes.button} content="Get Started" color='white' />
                <Button ClassName={classes.button} content="Contact Us" color='blue' onClick = {handleClickOpen} />
                <Dialog
                  open={open}
                  onClose={handleClose}
                  aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
                  aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
                >
                  <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"Use Google's location service?"}</DialogTitle>
                  <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                      Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous location data to
                      Google, even when no apps are running.
                    </DialogContentText>
                  </DialogContent>
                  <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                      Disagree
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
                      Agree
                    </Button>
                  </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item lg={6} xs={12}>
            <img src={Image} className={classes.image} />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

EDIT: Here is the custom button component I'm using

```
import React from 'react';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { styled } from '@material-ui/styles';
import createBreakpoints from "@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button"

const breakpoints = createBreakpoints({});


const CustomButton = styled(Button)({
    border: '2px solid #FFFFFF',
    borderRadius: 80,
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 20px',
    textTransform: 'none',
    marginBottom: '20px',
    marginRight: '30px',
    marginLeft: '30px',
    [breakpoints.up("lg")]: {
        marginLeft: '0px',
    },
});

const BlueButton = styled(CustomButton)({
    background: '#0071F7',
    color: 'white',
    '&:hover': {
        background: 'white',
        color: '#0071F7',
    },
});

const WhiteButton = styled(CustomButton)({
    background: 'white',
    color: '#0071F7',
    '&:hover': {
        background: '#0071F7',
        color: 'white',
    }
});

const ButtonType = styled(Typography)({
    fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
    fontWeight: 450,
});

export default class Title extends React.Component {
  render (){
    if(this.props.color == 'white'){
        return (
            <WhiteButton gutterBottom>
                <ButtonType>
                    {this.props.content}
                </ButtonType>
            </WhiteButton>
        )
    } else{
        return(
            <BlueButton gutterBottom>
                <ButtonType>
                    {this.props.content}
                </ButtonType>
            </BlueButton>
        )  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Any error on clicking of button?

Comment: @ravibagul91 nothing in the console

Comment: Are the buttons are visible with correct content?

Comment: @ravibagul91 yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a good idea to use the onClick-prop you provided with to your CustomButton and set it on your button.

```
export default class Title extends React.Component {
  render () {
    if(this.props.color == 'white'){
        return (
            <WhiteButton onClick={this.props.onClick} gutterBottom>
                <ButtonType>
                    {this.props.content}
                </ButtonType>
            </WhiteButton>
        )
    } else{
        return(
            <BlueButton  onClick={this.props.onClick}  gutterBottom>
                <ButtonType>
                    {this.props.content}
                </ButtonType>
            </BlueButton>
        )  
    }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As per the [API Doc](https://material-ui.com/api/button/), there is no `props` called `content` for `Button`  instead use `children` like,

```
<Button className={classes.button} children="Get Started" style={{color:'white'}} />
<Button className={classes.button} children="Contact Us" style={{color:'blue'}} onClick = {handleClickOpen} />
```

**Update**

You are using `Button` name to your custom component and `material-ui` also have the component with same name. As you are using both in same place there is a conflict and not a error from `material-ui` which one to use and your functionality is not working. This is probably the problem.

Try to change your custom button component name and check if it works.

**Update 2**

```
if(this.props.color == 'white'){
        return (
            <WhiteButton gutterBottom>
                <ButtonType>
                    <Button onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.content}</Button> //You forgot to use Button here
                </ButtonType>
            </WhiteButton>
        )
    } else{
        return(
            <BlueButton gutterBottom>
                <ButtonType>
                    <Button onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.content}</Button>
                </ButtonType>
            </BlueButton>
        )  
    }
```

Comment: And there is no color:'blue' or 'white'
and also className and not ClassName

Comment: I should have specified, that is my own button class, not the material one. Those props are correct for that class.

Comment: @ConnorCarlson in this case post your custom Button component.

Answer (score -1):

you should use proper material-ui Button API(https://material-ui.com/api/button/)

```
 <Button  children="Get Started" style={{color:'white'}} />
    <Button  children="Contact Us" style={{color:'blue'}} onClick = {handleClickOpen} />
```

check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/3fl8r

Comment: Don't just say 'use something else'. He should have a reason why he didnt not use the default button. And further if he just uses another button he wont unnderstand what he did wrong..

Comment: @Azael that's why i provided link of code editor so that he can view his code issue!!